# pfsense + haproxy + stunnel as reverse proxy with load balancing and ssl terminaltion

Tags: load-balancing, reverse-proxy, haproxy, pfsense, stunnel

i have this topology as title says with a pfsense with installed haproxy and stunnel. Because i saw that haproxy can't do ssl termination i thought about stunnel. But i don't know how to set up it. My load balancer is not in the haproxy but in the default set up for load balancing in pfsense.

My main problem is to set up the reverse proxy in the pfsense with the HAproxy. After this is not hard to make it work the stunnel.

Regards,